# CSS for autocomplete widget

Tags: jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I want to use the autocomplete-widget from jqueryui.com (code below)
As you can see, they are using an external style sheet to make a good style.

How can I change the style of the "autocomplete-box"? Whats the id or class? Of course the autocomplete-suggestions aren't formatted.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
var availableTags = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
 });
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
 <input id="tags">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For more see here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style the input box any way you like by giving it an ID or class in your HTML, or if you want to style all Autocomplete boxes, with the selector

```
.ui-autocomplete-input {
    /* Your CSS here */
}
```

The autocomplete suggestions appear as a list below the input. It is formatted like this:

```
<ul class="ui-menu ui-autocomplete">
    <li class="ui-menu-item">Suggestion 1</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item">Suggestion 2</li>
</ul>
```

For future reference, I highly recommend getting familiar with your browser's inspector, e.g. [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) or Firefox's [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector). This can help you figure out HTML and CSS problems on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can access different componenets of the widget like so. ive made a plunkr for you to see it live. https://plnkr.co/edit/zMwsXhXtElU7VkvbJSvK?p=preview

to access the label :

```
.ui-widget label{
/* styles */
}
```

to access the input box of the plugin :

```
.ui-widget input{
/* styles */
}
```

to access the list of the plugin :

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item{
/* styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete box uses the `tags`  id  and it has a class called `ui-autocomplete-input`, so if you want to modify that element, you can include the class `ui-autocomplete-input` in your CSS.